# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on Simple Project XCode 4

Tags: xcode4, preferences, exc-bad-access

I need help with Xcode 4. I started something very simple, created a cocoa project and added a Window object and called it preferences.
Then in order to access this new window I linked it with the menu item "Preferences" action makeKeyAndOrderFront.
Just that, then when I run the application, the first time I click on the Preferences menu item, the preferences window open just fine ... after I close it and click again on the preferences menu item, then application crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the main.m

Does anyone knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, and I suspect we were both following the same trail of sparse tutorial information out there to make a Preferences window like Apple's.

I solved this issue just now by just setting `window = nil`, and not trying to get fancy with `[window autorelease]`.  As I tested, using `[window release]` would cause the issue instantly, while `[window autorelease]` would create that second-time crash.

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same behaviour. After some tests I understood that the problem is that the second time you click the preferences menu you send a message to the window that has been released (the object does not exist anymore). You can verify it by adding the 'NSZombieEnabled' environment variable set to 'YES' on the 'Arguments' Tab of your executables from XCode.

I solved this issue deselecting the 'release when closed' check in the interface builder for the window used as the preferences window.

Bye. Peter.